# .replace method not workkng in java

Tags: java, java.util.scanner

I want to do some sort of encryption but when I if I type a, it won't change to I, it will just print a. Why is this?

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class Encryption 
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        String normal = "", encoded, userResponse = "";

        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);

        System.out.println("Are you encoding or decoding? E or D");
        userResponse = sc.next();

        if (userResponse.equalsIgnoreCase("e"))
        {
            System.out.println("Enter the text that you want to encode:");
            normal = sc.next();

            encoded = normal.replace('a', 'i');
            encoded = normal.replace('b', 's');
            encoded = normal.replace('g', 'e');
            encoded = normal.replace('k', 'f');
            encoded = normal.replace('p', 'h');
            encoded = normal.replace('c', 'z');
            encoded = normal.replace('m', 'r');
            encoded = normal.replace('n', 't');
            encoded = normal.replace('o', 'd');
            encoded = normal.replace('l', 'j');
            System.out.println(encoded);
        }
        else if (userResponse.equalsIgnoreCase("d"))
        {
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: `encoded = normal.replace('l', 'j');` - what does `normal` contain at this point?

Comment: what is the purpose of the long _"llllllll..."_ is that intended?

Answer (score 5):

Since you keep using `normal` in *all* your calls of `replace`, only the last one works, because it writes over all other changes.

Remove `normal` variable, assign `encoded = sc.next();`, and use `encoded` in each call of `replace`, i.e.

```
encoded = sc.next();
encoded = encoded.replace('a', 'i');
encoded = encoded.replace('b', 's');
encoded = encoded.replace('g', 'e');
... // And so on
```

Comment: Obviously this must be common knowledge to most because of the down votes I have, but thank you for your help! :)

Comment: @BrendanHansen You are welcome! I have no idea why people downvoted your question, because there is nothing particularly wrong with it: that's the kind of knowledge that you get by making this particular mistake.